# SAS Import with Variable Folder

Tags: sas

I have a need to import a file from a a specific folder. This folder changes every month

I created my variable

```
%let reportingmonth=&sysfunc(intnx(month,&sysfunc(date()),-1),yymmn6);
```

This will return the previous month in a YYYYMM format e.g. 202207

I want to use this variable to import an xlsx file

```
   %let reportingmonth=%sysfunc(intnx(month,%sysfunc(date()),-1),yymmn6);
%put &reportingmonth;

LIBNAME mywork "%PATHNAME(ME)" ;
%TCPWIN ;
RSUBMIT INHERITLIB=(mywork) ;
     OPTIONS msglevel=i VALIDVARNAME= any;
     proc import datafile="\\myfilepath\folder1\CPA\NonAccrual\&reportingmonth.\CL\FinalOutput.xlsx"
           dbms=xlsx replace out=CLSummaryImport;
            SHEET="Sheet1";
           getnames=yes;
     run;
ENDRSUBMIT ;
```

However when I run the above I receive the below error.

WARNING: Apparent symbolic reference REPORTINGMONTH not resolved. 39 dbms=xlsx replace out=CLSummaryImport; 40 SHEET="Sheet1; 41 getnames=yes; 42 run; ERROR: Physical file does not exist,
\eagle.usaa.com\usaa\fsb\creditrisk\Credit_Policy_Analytics\NonAccrual&reportingmonth.\CL\CLSummaryOutput.

what have I doing wrong? Why is the file extension cutoff?

Importing with the direct path and no variable works as expected.

Comment: Write the filename your code is trying to use to the SAS log, say by using %PUT.  Make sure it has generated the name you are expecting.  Then make sure that is actually the name of the file.  Remember the file has to exist on the machine where the SAS code is running.  If you submit the code via a front end like SAS/Studio or Enterprise Guide that could be a different machine than the one you are using.

Comment: i've added a put and still get the same error. But i did notice theres a warning stating "Apparent symbolic reference REPORTINGMONTH not resolved."

Comment: Note that the file is also on a network drive. Importing this file using a direct path and no variable works fine.

Comment: If the macro variable does not exist then you did not run the first %LET statement or you used different names for the macro variable in the two places.

Comment: Looks like Tom's point is right.  But in general, for troubleshooting, use %PUT to put the full string you're trying to import to the log, then copy/paste that into a folder explorer window in Windows.  See if that works.  If not, see what's wrong with it. If it does work, then you might have access issues from the server.  (Are you running this local SAS or in EG/Studio from a server?)

Comment: And in the future here, please put the full log message in the question, you'll get a proper answer that way.

Comment: Thank you both for your quick replies. I've modified the original post to show everything being utilized and the error it is producing. Why is the extension being cut off? Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just define the macro variable on the computer where you intend to use it.

```
RSUBMIT INHERITLIB=(mywork) ;
     %let reportingmonth=%sysfunc(intnx(month,%sysfunc(date()),-1),yymmn6);
     OPTIONS msglevel=i VALIDVARNAME= any;
     proc import datafile="\\myfilepath\folder1\CPA\NonAccrual\&reportingmonth.\CL\FinalOutput.xlsx"
           dbms=xlsx replace out=CLSummaryImport;
            SHEET="Sheet1";
           getnames=yes;
     run;
ENDRSUBMIT ;
```

Comment: Thank you! Sorry for the misunderstanding earlier!

Comment: Tom, I'm trying the same thing for exporting however it's not responding the same as the import did. Stating that the file path doesn't exist.  and to ensure I have write permissions. I do have write access and it works fine when hardcoding the "Reportingmonth". Same RSUBMIT blocks and variable declared within it. Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Since your code is in an `rsubmit` block, you need to send your local session macro variable over to the remote session with `%syslput`. Your remote session is not aware of `&reportingmonth` unless you define it there or send it over.

I usually just send over all local session user macro variables to the remote session with the keyword `_USER_`. This is helpful if you have dozens of macro variables that you need to reference but don't want to define them all manually.

```
options autosignon=yes
        sascmd='!sascmd'
        ;

%let test = hello world!;

%syslput _USER_ / remote=mysess;

rsubmit mysess;
    %put &test;
endrsubmit;
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with that. Based on the code im using, would you insert the %syslput before the libname statement? Could you place the new syntax in my existing code?

Comment: You would place it before `rsubmit`. Give your rsubmit session a name, (e.g. `rsubmit mysess;` then use `%syslput _USER_ / remote=mysess`.